# how would one create different drop shadow sizes in SASS?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I know this is not gonna be used in any practical way, but how would one create different drop shadow sizes?

```
 .item-title a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: $some_lovely_button;
    box-shadow: $some_boxshadow_love px;
 }
```

Can I actually make a space after the variable? Will it be able to read now if i parse e.g. 5 to the variable, then it will put 5 px;
Obviously, if I put $some_boxshadow_lovepx it's a whole different variable.
I hope what i want to achieve is clear :D Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use concatenation or interpolation methods.

```
.item-title a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: $some_lovely_button;
    box-shadow: #{$some_boxshadow_love} px;
    box-shadow: {$some_boxshadow_love} + px;
     }
```

Comment: It marks the px as bad now in my sublime text, like an error

Comment: @ThorbenLüpkes did you add # before the variable name? edited

Comment: Worked as a charm. just notice you have to append the value (px/vh or anything) to the curly brackets like so:    font-size: #{$some_border_love}vw;

Answer (score 0):

Just use a mixin

```
=shadow($pixel, $pixel2, $pixel3, $color)
    box-shadow: $pixel, $pixel2, $pixel3, $color
```

When you use it

```
+shadow(2px, 2px, 0, green)
```

Or

```
+shadow(5px, 3px, 5px, red)
```

That way you can create whatever size or type you want anywhere. BTW I am using sass, not scss